# A Shared Idemponent repository for multiple file adapters

Tags: file, repository, duplicates, apache-camel

My purpose is to not to read same files again and again from a shared directory by different applications.

Is there a sharable idemponent repository for multiple applications which use camel file component?

THNX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes read about the idempotentRepository on the Camel file doc page: http://camel.apache.org/file2

You can use a shared repository such as a JDBC based, so you can use a database table,
or write your own repository implementation.

You can also read more here: http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html

Comment: Hi Claus, I used fileStore repo but 2 application read same file when I paste the same file into the polling directory. And when I inspected the filestore file, I saw two same entry in it. Any ideas?

Comment: The out of box file repo is not clustered.